# Python returning minus error value

Tags: python, exception

I have just come across a Python code snippet that returns a negated error value:

```
except OSError, e:
            return -(e.errno or EFAULT)
        except:
            print_exc()
            return -EFAULT
```

What is the purpose or returning a negated error value?

Comment: Some applications might be expecting error codes as negative return values and application specific return codes as positive.

Answer (score 1):

Often applications use a negative return value to signify an error, and a positive value to signify a success.

For example, a `write` function might return either the number of bytes written, a positive number, or if there was an error, the error code as a negative number.

Comment: That's true, and I expect `e.errno` or `EFAULT` to be negative value. I don't understand the need to negate the error codes though